# Django server can not run, why?

Tags: django

E:\pythonwebproject\pythonweb>python manage.py runserver 
Validating models...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x01DE69F0> 

Traceback (most recent call last): 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper 
    fn(*args, **kwargs) 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 92, in inner_r 

    self.validate(display_num_errors=True) 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 277, in validate 

    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_ 

    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items(): 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors 

    self._populate() 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 72, in _populate 
    self.load_app(app_name, True) 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 96, in load_app 
    models = import_module('.models', app_name) 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module 
    __import__(name) 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 21, in <module> 
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 127, in <module> 
    class ContentType(models.Model): 

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 88, in __new__ 
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs)) 

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases 
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Answer (score 2):

[This bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18961) is the only resource I can find with similar symptoms. Are you using django 1.5? Try upgrading your python install to 2.7 and see if that rectifies the issue.

Comment: You come from the future, eh? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the development version of Django (soon to be 1.5) with Python 2.6. It only works with 2.7 and 3.3. You should either upgrade your Python version, or use the released Django version 1.4.

Comment: No you don't. There's no such thing. The last released version of Django is 1.4.

Comment: To be precise: Django 1.5 requires Python 2.6.5+, Snow Leopard comes with 2.6.1.